# q=modifiedAt or q=modifiedAt>aDate returns an empty array

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm using Orion-LD v1.4.0.
I have some entities of type Site in the context. My goal is to retrieve all context entities of type Site that where modified after a given date. But "q=modifiedAt" seems not to be supported by /ngsi-ld/v1/entities.

This request does return my entities:

> http://[::1]:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Site

But this request returns an empty array, whereas it should return them all:

> http://[::1]:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Site&q=modifiedAt

And this one returns an empty array as well, whereas it should return the ones that have been modified after january, the 1st:

> http://[::1]:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Site&q=modifiedAt>2023-01-01T00:00:00Z

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Issue created here: https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues/1458

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the PR https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/pull/1460.
So, just use a newer version of the broker and it should be OK.
Here's the issue: https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues/1458.